# my jquery slider works simultaneously. why?

Tags: jquery

As you can see in the code below, my jQuery slider is working but simultaneously. I can't understand why. I want my slides to be faded in and out respectively and I'm trying to achieve this using a `for` loop and in my mind everything should work: in each iteration, during 5 seconds each slide should be faded out, 5 seconds delay and then faded in. So each iteration should last for 11 second. But all slides are faded in and out simultaneously.

### JSFiddle

You can find the sources [here](https://jsfiddle.net/outlander/n5kduyhL/) in a JSFiddle.

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var images = $('img');
var imageLength = images.length;
for (var i = 0; i < imageLength; i++) {

    $(images[i]).animate( {'opacity':'0'}, 5000 ).delay( 5000 ).animate( {'opacity':'1'} );
}


});
```

### CSS

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width:80%;
    height:350px;

    margin: 30px auto;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;

    top:0;

}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
<div class="slider">
    <img id="1" src="https://i0.wp.com/themes.svn.wordpress.org/fine/1.0.59/screenshot.png" alt="" />
    <img id="2" src="https://i0.wp.com/themes.svn.wordpress.org/syn/1.0.2/screenshot.png" alt="" />
    <img id="3" src="https://i0.wp.com/themes.svn.wordpress.org/wordit/1.2.1/screenshot.png" alt="" />
</div>
</body>
```

Could you please help me with that? thank you.

Comment: Must be the world's tiniest fiddle!

Comment: Sorry. I added my fiddle

Comment: Please place your code in the question in case the third party site goes down.

Comment: my fiddle is now linked properly.

Comment: As you noticed when you tried to paste in the jsfiddle link, it said that you should paste your code to the question too. Why didn't you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting downvoted is because it's typically considered best practice on Stack Overflow to put your code in the question as well as posting a fiddle.  But I see you're new to SO, so we'll let it slide! :-)

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but I would use JQuery fadeIn and fadeOut to accomplish your task:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        count = ($(".slider :nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut(5000).next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
        $(".slider :nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
```

I've updated your Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xu9jm1ut/

Comment: Thank you. Yes I didn't know about jsfiddle rules.

Comment: and your fiddle is not what i'm after. I want all my slide to fade in and out one by one but in your fiddle just one slide is working and the two left, are not sliding.

Comment: So are you saying you only want 1 image displayed at a time, and you want them to swap in and out on each transition?  If so, you'll need to remove them once a transition is complete.

Comment: Yes. that's what I'm trying to do but with for loop. my question is why for loop is doing it's job simultaneously. I think in each iteration it should last 11 second and then goes to next iteration but it's doing all iterations at the same time.